# Reclaim free space after deleting NFS file

Tags: nfs, disk-space-utilization

I deleted a 137G file in a NFS mount (from a Linux host), and it dissapeared from the directory but the free space reported by `df` is still the same

- the NFS server is a NAS device with almost no logging information, but at least it shows the free space, which is the same as reported by `df`
- the file is not open - it's unused for a long time, it doesn't show in `lsof` (I also have rebooted the NAS device)
- the difference between the used space from `df -h` and `du -hs .` on the full disk is exactly 137G
- the NFS share is mounted with `soft,user` options

What could be causing this?

Comment: `df` uses fsstat call. Some server may use cached/precalculated value to avoid expensive operation.

Comment: @kofemann I guess those cached values would be cleared after a reboot

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the files doesn't actually delete the file. Restart or kill that process to release the file.

```
lsof +L1
```

use above command to find that which process is using a deleted file.

Comment: I run that command but none of the files shown there lies inside the NFS mount